# Changing Wordpress permalinks under Nginx: rewrite rule to avoid Google's punishment?

Tags: nginx, wordpress, rewrite

I have a site with a **WordPress blog** which has the usual permalink structure:

```
/%postname%/
```

But I'd like to **include the date** in the permalink:

```
/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/
```

So a post like this:

```
www.mysite.com/beautiful-title
```

would translate/redirect to this

```
www.mysite.com/2011/03/23/beautiful-title
```

I know I must **apply a rewrite rule** to send all previous permalinks (that are now indexed on search engines such as Google, Yahoo or Bing) to the new ones, because if I don't do so, all those links will get a 404, right?

What's the **right way to do that** in Nginx? That's the webserver I'm working with, but the structure of the rewrite rules is quite a mistery for me :(

********************* UPDATE ********************

Well, the question was finally solved thanks to the magic of WordPress. In fact, **I haven't had to do anything with Nginx** or rewrite rules.

The fact is, when Google shows a result of your WP blog, it goes to the link listed, but then **WordPress converts automatically this link to the right one** you've got according to your permalinks structure.

So I've just changed my permalinks structure that now has the date on the URL, and **everything is working properly**. No Google (or other search engines) punishment, after all ;)

Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the information on Wordpress database and some `SELECT`'s to assemble a from-to list of URLs that basically has the old URLS to the new URLS, like:

```
/beautiful-title /2011/03/23/beautiful-title
```

and then use this information to write a long, very long depending on the number of posts on your site, rewrite. It's not pretty. You would have a long file with:

```
location / {

    rewrite ^/beautiful-title/?$ /2011/03/23/beautiful-title permanent;
    rewrite ^/beautiful-title2/?$ /2011/03/22/beautiful-title2 permanent;
    ... and so on ...
}
```

Yes, you will have to put each of the old URLs pointing to the new ones, there's not much to do since the new URLs are depending on dates. The good news is that theoretically you must keep it up just for some time until the robots notice the *permanent redirect* (301) and update the database. The same can't be said about people who bookmarked your posts.

Comment: Uauh. I thought there would be an easy way to do that. We've got over 7.000 posts on the site, so making that list would be a tough task :(

Comment: Not really. A `SELECT` to get the to-from list, plus a script or `vi` macro to add `rewrite ..?$ .... permanent;` to the lines.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? I'm not an expert with MySQL, and though I know how to make a SELECT, I'm not sure the kind of SELECT you're talking about. In fact, shouldn't I make two SELECTs? One before setting the date on the permalinks, and one after, to get all the URLs and configure that file?

Comment: You have the post publishing dates already on the database, so you should be able to select them before changing the permalink scheme. Take a look here http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description